# Regex producing wrong results in google script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use regex to extract something from a string. I know I don't have to use the global operator as I only need one match but I am curious why it isn't working

```
var string = 'a02_ability10'

string.match(/(?:^a)([\d]+)/gi)
```

this doesn't give me any results.  remove the global operator it works. I have used it with the global operator in regex tester and it works.

Trying to get "02" out

Why isn't it working here?

Comment: returns array `["a02"]` is that what you expect (you never point out what you expect or what you actually get, so it's hard to know what your problem is ..) ... without /g it return `["a02", "02"]` ... so, it would be very nice if you would add **to the question** your expected result

Comment: As an aside, you should remove all that is useless in your pattern (8 characters to find)

Comment: What regex tester, And is it in JavaScript mode?

Comment: @keith regex101 and JaromandaX, it doesn't produce this result

Answer (score 0):

Without **gi**, it gives the full matched string and group matched string ([\d] i.e., 12)  at next position.(return Only first matched string )

var string = 'a12_ability10'

string.match(/(?:^a)([\d]+)/)

Result : ["a12", "12", index: 0, input: "a12_ability10"]

With **gi** :it will give only full matched string.

Result : ["a12"]

Please find below example for better understanding.

```js
var string = 'a12_ability10'

var result =string.match(/(?:^a)([\d]+)/)
console.log(result);

var string = 'a12_ability10'

var result =string.match(/(?:^a)([\d]+)/gi)
console.log(result);

var string = 'a12_a10'

var result= string.match(/(?:a)([\d]+)/);
console.log(result);


var result= string.match(/(?:a)([\d]+)/gi);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have just run your code in google script app and the logger output was
null
null
 [a12, 12]
 [a12, a10]
and therein lies my problem why is it giving null
Why is gi giving me the full result, previously I'd get first array[0] containing the full result and the second[1] containing my match i.e 'a12' why is the (?:) not matching and including the result